# Is there a means to keep an unlimited cross browser history?

Tags: software-rec, browser, browser-addons, data-visualization

Is there a browser addon or a webservice, which offers an unlimited browsing history?

I'm looking for a better way to find things on the internet **again** and recognized, that bookmarking isnt enough!

I have way too many bookmarks, and I don't bookmark the things that I'm looking for after a certain period of time.  History Tree sounded good as a start, but the [link is dead](https://superuser.com/questions/49192/is-there-a-browser-which-saves-history-as-a-graph).

I need a visual presentation of everything I see on the web with somekind of autotagging, autoindexing.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.archify.com/ could be an emerging solution. Will update here after testing the service!

Comment: Have you found a solution that satisfies you? Sadly the link is dead.